# Customize y axis in Tikz graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

[image]I would like to customize the y-axis in the graph below such that the numbers 1 and 2 in this axis are not superposed. Your input is very appreciated.

Here is the actual code:

```
\documentclass[english, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\usepackage{forest}


\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,arrows.meta,calligraphy}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \begin{axis}[
    %title={},
    xlabel={Size of the supermajority ($\alpha$)},
    ylabel={Maximum number of equilibria {\large \textbf{$N^{*}$}}},
    xmin=0.5, xmax=1,
    ymin=1, ymax=100,
    xtick={0.5, .6,.7, .8, .9, 1},
    ytick={1, 2, 10, 22, 34, 42, 52, 62, 82, 100, 110},
    legend pos=outer north east,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    xmajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    ]
    \addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=*,
    ]
    coordinates {
        (.5,2)(.6,22)(0.67,34)(0.7,42)(0.75,52)(.8,62)(0.9,82)(1,100)
    };
    \addlegendentry{Maximum number of equilibria}
    \addplot[
    color=red,
    mark=*,
    ]
    coordinates {
        (.5,1)(.6,1)(0.67,1)(0.7,1)(0.75,1)(.8,1)(0.9,1)(1,1)
    };
    \addlegendentry{minimum number of equilibria}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please have a look at [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192)

Comment: This is not an issue of Tikz or LaTeX. You have logaritmic axes and numbers `1` and `2` overlap. Simply, remove `1` from the `ytick` list.

Comment: I think you should clarify your question. Maybe update it with smtg like: How to adjust overlapping ticks? It is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nudge "1" down by 4pt using `yticklabel style={yshift={(\ticknum == 0 ? "-4pt" : 0)}}` and "2" up by 3pt using `yticklabel style={yshift={(\ticknum == 1 ? "3pt" : 0)}}`.

What the first key is saying is:

1. `yticklabel style =` ... Set the yticklabel style for the values given in `ytick={...}`
2. `yshift=` ... Move the yticklabel vertically
3. `\ticknum == 0 ?` ... Test if this is the first ticknum (Note that `tiknum` starts at 0)
4. `"-4pt"` ... If this is the first tick, apply a vertical shift downwards of 4pt
5. `: 0` ... Otherwise do nothing

I also added `enlarge y limits=true` to add some space between "1" and the x-axis.

This is the result:
[image]

This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[english, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9} % Compatability could be set to 1.15 or newest

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,arrows.meta,calligraphy}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \begin{axis}[
    %title={},
    xlabel={Size of the supermajority ($\alpha$)},
    ylabel={Maximum number of equilibria {\large \textbf{$N^{*}$}}},
    xmin=0.5, xmax=1,
    ymin=1, ymax=100,
    enlarge y limits=true,
    xtick={0.5, .6,.7, .8, .9, 1},
    ytick={1, 2, 10, 22, 34, 42, 52, 62, 82, 100, 110},
    yticklabel style={yshift={(\ticknum == 0 ? "-4pt" : 0)}},
    yticklabel style={yshift={(\ticknum == 1 ? "3pt" : 0)}},
    legend pos=outer north east,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    xmajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    ]
    \addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=*,
    ]
    coordinates {
        (.5,2)(.6,22)(0.67,34)(0.7,42)(0.75,52)(.8,62)(0.9,82)(1,100)
    };
    \addlegendentry{Maximum number of equilibria}
    \addplot[
    color=red,
    mark=*,
    ]
    coordinates {
        (.5,1)(.6,1)(0.67,1)(0.7,1)(0.75,1)(.8,1)(0.9,1)(1,1)
    };
    \addlegendentry{minimum number of equilibria}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @JBT You are welcome. Glad it was useful.

Comment: Can captions located inside of the graph?

Answer (score 2):

You could try, for example

```
yticklabels={,,10,22,34,42,52,62,82,100,110},
```

as demonstrated in the following:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    %title={},
    xlabel={Size of the supermajority ($\alpha$)},
    ylabel={Maximum number of equilibria {\large \textbf{$N^{*}$}}},
    xmin=0.5, xmax=1,
    ymin=1, ymax=100,
    xtick={0.5, .6,.7, .8, .9, 1},
    ytick={1, 2, 10, 22, 34, 42, 52, 62, 82, 100, 110},
    yticklabels={,,10,22,34,42,52,62,82,100,110},
    legend pos=outer north east,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    xmajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    ]
    \addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=*,
    ]
    coordinates {
        (.5,2)(.6,22)(0.67,34)(0.7,42)(0.75,52)(.8,62)(0.9,82)(1,100)
    };
    \addlegendentry{Maximum number of equilibria}
    \addplot[
    color=red,
    mark=*,
    ]
    coordinates {
        (.5,1)(.6,1)(0.67,1)(0.7,1)(0.75,1)(.8,1)(0.9,1)(1,1)
    };
    \addlegendentry{minimum number of equilibria}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @JBT could you update your question with a screenshot of what you have, and what you would like to receive. At the moment, it seems that I've misunderstood

Comment: @JBT Hi there, I'm not entirely sure why you seem to have proposed an edit to cmhughes's answer, with your explanation of what you would like as the edit reason. You should instead edit your original question (which you can do for yourself) to include the screenshot and the things that you would like help with so as to make the question clearer for everybody.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue of Tikz. Simply remove `1` from the `ytick` list.

[image]

Comment: I want to keep 1.